# How to convert string to datetime in java using joda time

Tags: java, jodatime

I am currently working on converting from date to string. After that I convert that string to datetime. But it error. Anyone can help me?

Here is the code.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String dt1 = outFormat.format(date1);


DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(dt1);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're doing entirely too much work.  Joda Time can convert for you in its [`parse(String, DateTimeFormatter)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) method.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dt1, formatter);
```

Alternatively, if your string were in ISO8601 format (that is, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`), you could just use `parse(String)` instead:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dt1);
```